# Is there a word for the concept of not repeating your parents' mistakes?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is such an odd question, I know, but I'm curious if such a thing has a one-or-two-word name. This may get Freudian, though I'm not expert there.

For example: person Y, a descendant of X, did not have a close relationship to X. Therefore, Y's behaviors and needs are formed by what they did, and didn't, get from X. This catalyst may move them to try and obtain that thing, or if they have children Z of their own, to not pass along the same mistakes. Though, they'll probably pass along new mistakes instead, thus repeating the cycle from a different perspective.

What is this cycle called? The *Cycle of Convictions*? *Generational Upcycling*? Something not explicitly saying "cycle"?

I just don't know. It feels like there should be a word out there for this concept.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer but: There was a financial advisor who advertised in the Playbill in Phoenix whose ad always said, “Intelligence is being able to learn from your mistakes. Wisdom is learning from the mistakes of others.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the idiom **breaking the cycle**. From The Free Dictionary:

> **[break the cycle](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/break+the+cycle)**: To not participate in dysfunctional and/or unhealthy behavior. Often, such behavior is commonplace in one's family, and the person breaking the cycle does so to keep it from continuing through future generations.

This definition speaks directly to the concept of not repeating one's parents' mistakes.

Comment: That may be as close as it comes. Thanks Richard.

Comment: @Werewoof Thanks. I had to break the cycle myself, but as you may know, it’s not as easy to do as one may think. The acorn doesn’t fall far from the tree.